# Mongoose: Using the same schema in two separate arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas, defined as following:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
 email: String,
 name: String,
 role: String,
 password: String
})

var raceSchema = new Schema({
 date: Date,
 name: String,
 location: String,
 time: String,
 register: String,
 participants: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
 registered_participants: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
})
```

As you can see, I reference the first schema twice in the second schema. If I add a reference to a user in one of the lists, everything is fine. But when I add a reference to the same user to the other list I get the following error: `Cast to [undefined] failed for value`

What causes this error? Is it related to the fact that the same schema is used twice in the second schema?

Edit:
I get the error when I call the following Express endpoint:

```
app.post('/race/:id/registered', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), (req, res) =>
  Race.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err, race) {
    if (err) return res.json({'Error': err})
    if (!race) return res.json({'Error': 'Race not found'})
    race.registered_participants.push(req.user)
    race.save(function (err, updatedRace) {
      if (err) return res.json({'Error': err})
      res.send(updatedRace)
    })
  })
)
```

Edit 2: The model definitions:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Race = mongoose.model('Race', raceSchema);
```

Comment: I have a hunch your issue is not the schema. Could you please add the code where you create a reference to the same user twice? (The failing case)

Comment: @MattGoodrich I have updated my question to include the code.

Comment: Can you also include any model definitions, please?

Comment: @MattGoodrich Added.

Comment: Isn't req.user an object containing a lot of stuff? Only the object id should be pushed to the array.

Comment: @MikaS You're right, that fixed the issue. The error happened only in the situation described above, so that threw me off guard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `findByIdAndUpdate` in your `POST` method instead:

```
app.post('/race/:id/registered', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), (req, res) =>
  Race.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
  { $push: { registered_participants: req.user } }, 
   function (err, race) {
      if (err) return res.json({'Error': err})
      res.send(race)
    })
)
```